# How do I add text to the span after some action is perform?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/nwT6v/1/

That's my script basically. How come?

I want to add text after clicking download to the `span`.

Comment: While linking to a live test case is useful, it shouldn't substitute for having a complete question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("li").click(function(o) {
    $(this).find('span').text("some text");
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TLpSJ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".className").click(function() {
    $(this).next("span").html("some text");
});​
```

Try this code.

When using $ to find selector by class, you need "." before class name. Also, if you write $(".className").next("span").html("some text") - it will add "some text" to all spans after .className, because $(".className") will be array of elements with class="className" in this case.

Comment: this works well, why did it get an instant downvote?

Answer (score 0):

This will make it work

```
$(".className").click(function() {
    $(".className").next("span").html("some text");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".className").click(function() {
    $(this).next('span').text("some text");
});​
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nwT6v/10/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".className").click(function(e) {

    $(e.currentTarget).next('span').html("some text");
});
```

Link:-
http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep_giet/nwT6v/11/